# How can I display a macOS progress pie loading icon next to files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, progress-bar

On macOS when a file is in the process of downloading or transfering, a pie loading icon is displayed next to the file. For example, here is a file mid download form Chrome:

[image: n]

I would like to achieve the same thing in my Electron/Node app.

How can I display a progress pie loading icon next to files with Node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, the way this is done with [extended attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes), specifically the `com.apple.progress.fractionCompleted` one. `com.apple.progress.fractionCompleted` value can range from `0.01` (1%) to `1` (100%).

The Node module [fs-xattr](https://github.com/LinusU/fs-xattr) seems to allow you to manage extended file attributes with ease.

```
const xattr = require('fs-xattr')

await xattr.set('fileDownload.mp4', 'com.apple.progress.fractionCompleted', '0.25')
```